# Android Calendar: onActivityResult's resultCode is always 0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-calendar

I develop an Android application that prompt the calendar application to edit events.

I use `startActivityForResult()` to open the Calender. After editing and saving the event,  `resultCode` is always 0 inside `onActivityResult()`.

I saw many answers related to "onActivityResult resultCode always returns 0".
This is because of not using the `setResult()` and `finish()` in the 2nd activity.

But in my case, I am calling the Android calendar application (not a custom activity).

The code to prompt the Android calendar:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
//set the event details
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

To trigger when calender is saved or cancelled

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //resultCode always returns 0.
    switch(requestCode) {
    case 1: 
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Whether I click "Save" or "Cancel" in the calendar app, the `resultCode` always gives 0.

additionally I need to get the data back from the calendar intent.But The intent "data" in the onActivityResult also returns null.

Could anyone explain why it happens? Is there any way to know if user clicks "Save" or "Cancel"?

Comment: is the calendar designed to return a value? if not it will always return a 0.

Comment: I don't think Android (Google) Calendar will return any result, at least it's not specified in [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html).

Comment: If it is so, Does Android calender provider provide any methods to know whether user click save the calender or Cancel?

Comment: try to ignore the `resultCode` for a moment. Do you get any `Intent data` back? `if(data != null)` does it return `true`? can you get `data.getExtras()?` `bundle` out of it? print it to logcat, what do you have in it?

Comment: "data" always returns null. The following Log is displayed in logcat. " Can't update model with a Calendar cursor until it has seen an Event cursor."

Answer (score 4):

You can check for lastId of newly added calendar event, if it has not changed, then result is actually CANCELLED, otherwise it is OK

```
val projection = arrayOf(CalendarContract.Calendars._ID)
cursor = contentResolver.query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null)
if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
    val lastId = cursor.getLong(0)
    // compare lastId with a previous one, if not changed - result is CANCELLED
}
```